# React native not overlapping statusbar

Tags: react-native, statusbar, overlapping

Im learing React native but i dont understand how to get everything to not overlap with the status bar.

[image: this is how it looks like]

```
I have tried
translucent={true/flase}
hidden
```

Comment: Please edit your question to insert the actual image rather than inserting a link to the image somewhere else.

Comment: @Frank Fajardo Stackoverflow does not let me do it :/

Comment: please see [how to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: @FrankFajardo need 10 reputation for that!

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour, one solution is to add a padding to your top level view equal to current height of status bar or have a `StatusBarView` that has same height as the status bar.

Refer to this plugin https://github.com/jgkim/react-native-status-bar-size for listening to status bar height changes.

For e.g

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StatusBar} from 'react-native';
import StatusBarSizeIOS from 'react-native-status-bar-size';

const STATUS_BAR_EXTRA_PADDING = 2;
const DEFAULT_STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT = 10;

class StatusBarView extends Component {
  state = { 
    statusBarHeight: _.get(StatusBarSizeIOS, 'currentHeight', DEFAULT_STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT);
  }  

  _handleStatusBarSizeDidChange = (statusBarHeight) => this.setState({ statusBarHeight })

  componentDidMount() {
    StatusBarSizeIOS.addEventListener('didChange', this._handleStatusBarSizeDidChange);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: this.state.statusBarHeight + STATUS_BAR_EXTRA_PADDING,
        }}
      >
        <StatusBar {...this.props} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default StatusBarView;
```

Now inside your screens you could do something like

```
import StatusBarView from '{view_path}';
...
render() {
  return (
    <View>
       <StatusBarView barStyle="default" />
       <View>{rest of the view}</View>
    </View>
  );
}
```